# rspec flow isn't understandable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

In my acceptance test, I want to test the value of gift.available_quantity which is virtual attribute:

```
  def available_quantity
    pendings_orders = Order.where(status: 'pending')
    order_lines_pending = OrderLine.where(order_id: pendings_orders)
    gift_quantity_pending = order_lines_pending.sum do |oline|
      return oline.quantity if oline.gift_ean13 == ean13
    end
    quantity - gift_quantity_pending
  end
```

I don't test my code, but it's not the problem.

The problem is that my rspec evaluate the value of my gift.available_quantity before creating my fake order:

```
require 'acceptance_helper'

resource 'Gifts' do
  header 'Accept', 'application/json'
  header 'Content-Type', 'application/json'
  header 'Authorization', :authorization

  get '/api/v1/gifts' do
    let!(:member) { create(:member, id: 1) }

    let(:user) { create(:user, :activated, member: member) }
    let(:token) { Knock::AuthToken.new(payload: { sub: user.id }).token }
    let(:authorization) { "Bearer #{token}" }

    let!(:delivery_address) { create(:delivery_address, :favorited, member: member) }
    let!(:gifts) { create_list(:gift, 2, :enabled, quantity: 4) }

    let(:order_lines) { create(:order_line, gift_ean13: gifts.first.ean13, quantity: 1, order_id: order.id) }
    let(:order_lines2) { create(:order_line, gift_ean13: gifts.last.ean13, quantity: 2, order_id: order.id) }

    let!(:order) { create(:order, member: member, delivery_address: delivery_address) }


    example_request 'Get gift list' do
      expected_response = {
        gifts: [
        {
        id: gifts.first.id,
        name: gifts.first.name,
        description: gifts.first.description,
        reward_price: gifts.first.reward_price,
        quantity: gifts.first.quantity,
        date_from: gifts.first.date_from,
        date_to: gifts.first.date_to,
        image: nil,
        quantity_alert: gifts.first.quantity_alert,
        available_quantity: 3
      },
      {
        id: gifts.last.id,
        name: gifts.last.name,
        description: gifts.last.description,
        reward_price: gifts.last.reward_price,
        quantity: gifts.last.quantity,
        date_from: gifts.last.date_from,
        date_to: gifts.last.date_to,
        image: nil,
        quantity_alert: gifts.last.quantity_alert,
        available_quantity: 2
      }
    ]
  }

      expect(status).to eq(200)
      expect(response_body).to eq(expected_response.to_json)
    end
  end
end
```

My order isn't created before, so gift.avalaible_quantity isn't good...

Can someone help me understand "RSpec flow"?

Comment: not really sure what you mean, that rspec evaluares `gift.avalaible_quantity` before you create the orders. Isn't this method evaluated when the endpoint is hit? You don't show any code where you evaluate this method. Also, side note - you should assign variables to `gifts.first` and `gifts.last` and reuse them - it will make the test faster by avoiding repeated db lookups,

Comment: Thank's for the answer.

When i'm debugging, i pass first in "def available_quantity" (i don't have any order here) and then, i pass in "example_request" (and i have an order).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that your order_lines aren't being created before the spec runs.

Use `let!` to create them instead so they exist when the `available_quantity` method runs.

```
let!(:order_lines) { create(:order_line, gift_ean13: gifts.first.ean13, quantity: 1, order_id: order.id) }
let!(:order_lines2) { create(:order_line, gift_ean13: gifts.last.ean13, quantity: 2, order_id: order.id) }
```